# Some problems when export eclipse project using slick 2D

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar, slick2d

I have done a small RPG in Eclipse IDE. Now I want to share it with some friends who are not using IDE.

I read that I need to export my project into .jar or executable jar. Well these to process are not able to finish without errors.

This is my project: [The hierarchy of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK6TM.png).

I will show you the step I am following to export:

1. Right-click on the project > Export > JAR file ([Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L78Au.png))
2. Add my project to the .jar ([Export options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeN1Y.png))
3. Add my package and the main class ([Export options 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5INBS.png))
4. Then I click on finish and then the errors appears ([The errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYNBc.png))

After that the .jar come in the folder but doesn't work at all.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi Nwork, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you include your images in-line with the question?

Comment: Those look like they're identified as *warnings*. What's the *error* when you try to run the final jar?

Comment: @nitind When I try to run it there is nothing happen

Brydenr I can't that was the only option I had... And my questions is why that my .jar file doesn't work

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this tool:

https://ninjacave.com/jarsplice

Here´s a tutorial, how to export the Slick2D-App (But It´s in german):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8wwewUqg9E